# What is the relationship between zero-inflated binomial and Bin(n,p) distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

Hi just could anyone explain the relationship between zero-inflated binomial and $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ distribution? I think zero-inflated binomial should be a kind of mixture and $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ and other distribution, but I am not sure how to explain the $π$

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 
   (1 − π) + π (1 − p)^n & \text{ when } x = 0\\
   π \, {{n}\choose{x}}  \, p^x  (1-p)^{n-x}\,,\;& \text{ when } x = 1,2,3,...,n\\
   0\,, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

where $n$ is a positive integer, $0 ≤ p ≤ 1$ and $0 ≤ π ≤ 1$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right it is a mixture model which with probability $\pi $ is a standard binomial distribution and with probability $1-\pi $ is equal to 0. Therefore as $\pi $ approaches 1 the distribution approaches the standard binomial distribution.